# jquery open accordion from link

Tags: jquery, accordion

What am I doing wrong.
The accordion works, but when I try to open it from external link (fx. mysite.com/mypage.php#2) - it wont open the accordion!

My header is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
     active: false,
     collapsible: true,
     autoHeight: false,
     navigation: true,
     header: '.menuitem'
   }); 
   $(".menuitem").click(function(event){
     window.location.hash=this.hash;
   });
  });
  </script>
```

My html is:

```
  <div id="accordion">
  <a class="menuitem" href="#1">Header 1</a>
  <!-- accordion panel --><div>
  CONTENT 1</>
  <!-- end accordion panel --></div>
  <a class="menuitem" href="#2">Header 2</a>
  <!-- accordion panel --><div>
  CONTENT 2</>
  <!-- end accordion panel --></div>
  <!-- end accordion -->
```

Comment: external link means ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working code - [Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ashis/Ct2n3/5/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#accordion").accordion({
         active: false,
         collapsible: true,
         autoHeight: false,
         navigation: true,
         header: 'a.menuitem'
    }); 

    $(".menuitem").click(function(event){
        window.location.hash=this.hash;
    });

    //get the hash value
    var locationHash = window.location.hash;

    //split the value
    var hashSplit = locationHash.split('#');

    //get the tab number
    var currentTab = hashSplit[1];

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        //open the tab for the current hash
        $("#accordion").accordion({ active: parseInt(currentTab)-1 });
    }, 1000);

});
</script>


</head>



<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <a class="menuitem" href="#1">Header 1</a>
  <!-- accordion panel -->
  <div>
    CONTENT 1  
  </div>

  <a class="menuitem" href="#2">Header 2</a>
  <div>
    CONTENT 2
  </div>
  <!-- end accordion -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ashis
Your code works perfectly only, every DIV has the same size, so, when I have a DIV with 2 lines, there is a lot of white space beneath. When it contains a lot of information, the DIV is nicely filled.

Comment: Meanwhile I found the solution.

Putting:

       ---     heightStyle: content,      ---

in the JS code, this solves the problem.

Comment: Any idea how to let the choosen anchor scroll to the top?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($.url().hash.length) {
    var item = $.url().hash;    
    $('#accordion').accordion({active: item - 1}); // since you started numbering at 1 and not 0.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, though not a perfect solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $hash = window.location.hash;
    var $acc = $hash ? $hash : 1;
    $("#accordion").accordion({
     active: false,
     collapsible: true,
     autoHeight: false,
     navigation: true,
     header: '.menuitem',
     activate: $acc
   });
});
```

Many changes might be required..

Answer (score -1):

Your accordeon is a dynamic element in your page (driven with some javascript code).

Setting an html anchor in your url (like #2) will not trigger the accordeon code, you are simply instructing the browser to navigate to the anchored element !

You will need to add some javascript code to your page to get the value of the anchor and pass this parameter to your accordeon widget.