# open accordion panel from external anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Asked this question a few weeks ago, but have not been able to find a solution -  I'm a code novice, so I'll do my best to be more specific.

I have a page with an accordion - it's built-in as a short code that comes with the site theme. I have links in external pages that have anchor tags that take you to the accordion page - right now when those links are clicked, user is taken to the term but the panel does not open. I would like for the panel of the accordion to also open. As-is, all the panels are closed when you get to the page. Here is the code I have so far to remove the 'closed' class when a link w/an anchor is clicked:

```
var anchor = window.location.hash.substring(1);
$('.' + anchor).removeClass('su-spoiler-closed');
```

I have not been able to get it to work, perhaps I don't have it in the right spot? Maybe jquery is not working on the page in general?

Comment: you can check if jQuery is not working properly on the console.

Comment: this sounds like a wordpress page - am i correct? Why dont you go to the accordion page and take a look at the accordion when it IS expanded?? this would give you an idea about what you will need to do to manually open it. For example, removing 'closed' class may be good, you may also need to add an 'open' class... From  what we learn there, we can then tailor your jquery code to do what you need.

Comment: what are you using to create the accordion?

Comment: You can easily detect your problem using the developer tools of your fav browser. Here's a tutorial of how to use in [chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) and [firefox](http://getfirebug.com/javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You may also use CSS, it's easier for us novices.

```
/*accordion ids' unhide*/
    #id:target{
        display:block;
    }
/* end css */
```

link: www.website.com/page.htm#id

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is here: [jquery open accordion from link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932607/jquery-open-accordion-from-link)

You just need to get the hash content from current url and change the accordion.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming jQuerUI's accordion

Basically, you want to listen for the action on load and use the API to set the desired element.

API:  http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

you must class a parent wrapper of your accordion (here, as .parent) for this selector syntax to work:

```
$(function(){
    var anchor = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    $('.parent a[href$="' + anchor+ '"]').ready(function() {
          var index = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
          $( ".parent" ).accordion( "option", "active", parseInt(index,10) );
    });
});
```