# Link to anchor and open accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

How do I open an accordion panel by using an external anchor link?

I've tried using an anchor link and it just loads the page, without opening the panel.

What I'm trying to achieve is that when the anchor link is clicked, the page loads, scroll to the panel and then open the accordion.

This link is the one that will anchor to the other page and should open the accordion:

```
 <a class="linkTo" href="/project#<?php the_sub_field('area_link'); ?>">
```

This is the code I am using to open the accordion on click:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".accordion .accord-header").click(function() {
     // for active header definition
     $('.accord-header').removeClass('on');
     $(this).addClass('on');

     // accordion actions
     if($(this).next("div").is(":visible")){
       $(this).next("div").slideUp(600);
       $(this).removeClass('on');
     } else {
       $(".accordion .accord-content").slideUp(600);
       $(this).next("div").slideToggle(600);
     }
  });
});
```

This is the accordion structure:

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accord-header" id="<?php the_sub_field('area_link'); ?>">Accordion 1</div>
    <div class="accord-content">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open accordion panel from external anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901977/open-accordion-panel-from-external-anchor-link)

Comment: You can check `window.location` value on page-load, to decide whether to open that accordion or not.

Comment: @Yannjoel I read that, but it's not the same, they are using jQueryUI

Comment: What do you mean @AlexYokisama

Comment: This answer should still be able to solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/43743091/6886695

Comment: The problem is that accordion does not open after you get to the page with a link, containing id, right? Inside `$(document).ready()` check if `window.location` contains element-id. If so, do what you need to open the accordion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `window.location.hash` on document ready to initialize your accordion.

```
$(function () {
    var $accordionSecion = $(window.location.hash);
    if ($accordionSecion.length) {
       $(window).scrollTop($accordionSecion.offset().top);
       $accordionSecion.addClass('on');
    }
});
```

You can probably use same handler with [onhashschange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) listener to handle click on accordion titles.

Good luck. :)

Comment: I've added a bit of code to my original answer as an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var hash = window.location.hash;
 if (hash) {
   var element = $(hash);
   if (element.length) {
   element.trigger('click');
 }
 }
});
```

try above code on the page where you want to open the accordion.

Comment: Just put this code in the same file where your accordions are. Make sure the hash you are attaching to the url is same as the ID of the accordion and it should work fine. Let me know if you need any other help.